# media query for vertical scroll

Tags: css, media-queries

Is there a way to detect vertical scroll distance with a media query?

It seems that media queries are designed around detecting the medium (shocking right :P) so things like browser height are testable, but not specifically how far down the page is scrolled.

If is not possible, but you know a way in JS (not jQuery) feel free to post!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible with a CSS media query, but I do know that the scroll height can be found in JavaScript using `window.pageYOffset`. If you wanted to run this value through a function every time the users scrolled up or down on a page, you could do something like

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunctionHere(window.pageYOffset);
};
```

Or just:

```
window.onscroll = scrollFunctionHere;
```

If the function itself checked the value of `window.pageYOffset`.

For more advice on how to do use `window.onscroll` efficiently in JavaScript, refer to [mynameistechno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690891/1846065).

**Important note on efficiency**: running a function every single time a scroll event is emitted can tear through CPU cycles if anything non-trivial is performed in the callback. Instead, it is good practice to only allow a callback to run so many times per second. This has been termed "debouncing".

Simple debounced scroll event handler code below. Notice how the text toggles between "HELLO" and "WORLD" every 250ms, rather than every single frame:

```js
var outputTo = document.querySelector(".output");
var timeout_debounce;

window.addEventListener("scroll", debounce);

function debounce(event) {
    if(timeout_debounce) {
        return;
    }

    timeout_debounce = setTimeout(clearDebounce, 250);
// Pass the event to the actual callback.
    actualCallback(event);
}

function clearDebounce() {
    timeout_debounce = null;
}

function actualCallback(event) {
// Perform your logic here with no CPU hogging.
  outputTo.innerText = outputTo.innerText === "HELLO"
    ? "WORLD"
    : "HELLO";
}
```

```css
p {
  padding: 40vh;
  margin: 20vh;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p class="output">Test!</p>
```

Comment: I fixed the capitalization error in my answer and added something referring to your answer for more information on use of `window.onscroll`. Just for the record, I chose not to add more information to my answer because I assume that developers who wanted to use the JavaScript technique would do their own research on `window.onscroll`. @mynameistechno

Answer (score 22):

First off, the accepted answer doesn't work.

The correct name is

```
window.onscroll
```

and not

```
window.onScroll
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll

Second, this is horribly inefficient as the function is called way more than it needs to and can make the page laggy when scrolled. From John Resig:

http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Much better to use a timer that runs every 150 ms or so - something like:

```
var scrolled = false;

window.onscroll = function() {
  scrolled = true;
}

setInterval(function(){
  if (scrolled) {
    scrolled = false;
    // scrollFunction()
  }
}, 150);
```

Comment: This probably would have been better off as a comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: A timer is an incredibly fragile and bad idea to implement this. If you are for some reason doing some incredibly computationally expensive computation on scroll you'd want to use Date(), performance.now(), or even a counter to check time passed. However the `.onscroll` is _designed_ to be overridden, changing a simple CSS property on scroll would not be laggy at all

Comment: Regardless whether `onscroll` is *designed* to be overriden or not, it's an event handler, and scrolling *is known* to fire up a lot of events, so doing a lot of stuff in the handler is a bad idea for that reason (and not because of the merit of overriding). On a related note, because of this, for example, iOS did not fire `scroll` event until user *finishes* scrolling. Not until recent versions if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: instead of having a timer, which as @Downgoat said is fragile, it would be a better idea to use the event handler `onscroll` which fires many events. The way to combat those "too many events" is by checking how many ms have passed since the last time the `onscroll` function was executed, and executing it again only if that ms value is greater than a certian interval value.

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery you have the method .scrollTop()

http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

This example make a div scroll with the window scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){            
        $("div").css("margin-top", $(window).scrollTop())   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solution.f https://jsfiddle.net/oravckzx/1/

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.post-sidebar').each(function(){
var ScrollTopVar = $(window).scrollTop();
     
    var OffsetTopVar = $(this).offset().top;
        var OuterHeightVar = $(this).outerHeight();
         var PositionVar = OffsetTopVar-(OuterHeightVar*1.1);
        if (ScrollTopVar >= PositionVar) {
            $('.hide') .css('background','green').css('font-size','12px')
            $('.post-sidebar') .css('background','orange').css('font-size','12px')
            $('.hide') .css('background','green').css('font-size','12px')
            $('.post-sidebar') .css('background','gray').css('font-size','12px')
            document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = ScrollTopVar;
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = PositionVar;
        
        }else {
        $('.hide') .css('background','yellow').css('background','yellow')
        $('.hide') .css('background','yellow')
        $('.hide') .css('background','yellow')
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ScrollTopVar;
        document.getElementById("demo12").innerHTML = ScrollTopVar;
        document.getElementById("demo13").innerHTML = ScrollTopVar;
        document.getElementById("demo14").innerHTML = ScrollTopVar;
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = PositionVar;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.red {height:100px;
background:red;margin-bottom:20px;}

.hide {height:50px;background:blue;margin-bottom:20px;}

.post-sidebar {
height:50px;
background:yellow;
margin-bottom:20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
font: normal 700 34px Lato, sans-serif;
padding-right: 20px;
width: 452px;
}
.p {
  font: normal 700 14px Lato, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red"><p id="demo"></div>
<div class="red"></div><p id="demo12">ok
<div class="red"><p id="demo13">ok</div>


<div class="post-sidebar"><p id="demo2"></p><p>lizard</p></div>

<div class="hide"><p id="demo2">If reaches to chosen class in html, saves value of ScrollTopVar (as distance from top) to separate variable as eventually PositionVar (which is the distance from top to the chosen class in html, - and that specific distance depends of device which is doing it), and then does certain action if ScrollTopVar value matches or exceeds PositionVar value. Else sets it back if needed, if not including Else it remains as it once met the value. <p id="demo3"></div>




<div class="red"><p id="demo14">ok</div>
<div class="red"><p id="demo"></div>
<div class="red"><p id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Is the fiddle exactly the same as the snippet?