# How can I only let my header menu shrink when the screen size is larger than 700px by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So here's my website below:
[KaiNanfelt_Music](https://www.holisticpronerd.com/KaiNanfelt_Music/)

I tried to make my header(menu) shrink when scrolling, the whole codes looks like this :

So it works on all screen, but I want it to only work when the screen size is larger than 700px, what should I do with it and any suggestion? Thank you!

```js
// When the user scrolls down 80px from the top of the document, resize the navbar's padding and the logo's font size
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.padding = "0px";
    document.getElementById("menu").style.margin = "0px 0px 0px 10px";
    document.getElementById("site-title").style.fontSize = "3.5em";
    document.getElementById("site-title").style.float = "left";
    document.getElementById("site-title").style.margin = "20px 0 10px 0";
    document.getElementsByClassName("menu").style.float = "right";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.padding = "10px";
    document.getElementById("site-title").style.fontSize = "6.8em";
    document.getElementById("site-title").style.float = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#menu {
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffffff;
  ;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <button class="nav-button">Toggle Navigation</button>
  <div id="site-title">
    <a href="#" title="home" rel="home">
      Home
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS where you can**
Why not doing it in `CSS`?
`JavaScript` should not do styling in the first place, but well, you can do it if you like. I don't recommend it. If you can do it in `CSS`, then it is definitely the best way. The problem that we face here is, that we cannot track the scroll position without `JavaScript`. Therefore, this part must be in `JavaScript`.

**Horizontal maximum**
You can use the `@media query` in `CSS` for this part. You can also set or unset the classes in javascript (if you need to toggle it for example).

**Scrolling**
Please have a look at this post here:
[media query for vertical scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922731/media-query-for-vertical-scroll)
It also explains, what I had in mind. The call is expensive because it will call the `onScroll-function` over and over non-stop. But he has also a solution to that. I forked a solution based on this post.

```js
var nav = document.querySelector(".your-nav");
var timeout_debounce;

window.addEventListener("scroll", debounce);

function debounce(event) {
  if (timeout_debounce) {
    return;
  }
  timeout_debounce = setTimeout(clearDebounce, 100);
  actualCallback(event);
}

function clearDebounce() {
  timeout_debounce = null;
}

function actualCallback(event) {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 80) {
    nav.classList.add('scrolled');
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove('scrolled');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.get-smaller {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
}

.your-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

.your-nav.scrolled ul {
  background: purple;
}

.your-nav ul {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: wheat;
}

.your-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.your-nav li:last-child() {
  background: red;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .get-smaller {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .your-nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="get-smaller">
  <span>I will get smaller if the viewport is smaller than 700px</span>
</div>

<nav class="your-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use documentElement with clientWidth inside a conditional statement to see if the screen width is larger than 700, if it is, run your function...

***NOTE:*** I used 600 pixels in my example as the viewport in the snippit is lower than 700

```js
var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
console.log('current viewport: ' + viewportWidth)
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (viewportWidth > 600) {
    //<-- console.log just to illustrate that the sizing works, resize your screen and test
    console.log(' Window is larger than 600 px');
    // run your scrollFunction()
  }
};
```

```html
<!--Force a scroll using break tags for testing--><br>
'view in full screen'<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```